# CodeIgniter routing not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, url-routing

I am having problems with my routing. My default controller (mysite.com) will work, but if I try anything else (e.g. mysite.com/dashboard), it goes to a server based 404, not a CodeIgniter one. It's very confusing, as at the moment I only have 2 paths in my routes.php file. Here are the non-commented sections of my routes.php file:

```
$route['404_override'] = '';

$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

My controller is located in /application/controllers/pages.php.

I don't think its a .htaccess issue (as it can get to the default controller), but here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|styles|scripts|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1

#<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
#    mod_gzip_on       Yes
#    mod_gzip_dechunk  Yes
#    mod_gzip_item_include file      \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
#    mod_gzip_item_include handler   ^cgi-script$
#    mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^text/.*
#    mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^application/x-javascript.*
#    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime      ^image/.*
#    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
#</IfModule>
```

**Edit**

Here is the pages controller:

```
<?php

        class Pages extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {       
                //Construct it's parent
            parent::__construct();

            //Check login
            //$this->load->model('pages_model');
        //$this->pages_model->getLoginStatus();

    }


    public function view($page = 'dashboard')
    {

        //If the file doesn't exist
        if ( ! file_exists('/var/www/vhosts/mysite/httpdocs/library/application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }       

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

        //Load all necessary views
        $this->load->view('templates/head', $data); 
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Stupid question but, the method 'view' does exist for the pages controller?

Comment: Yes, it is the only method in the pages class. I'll add the class in the code above.

Comment: Is it because you have declared your default controller as controller/method, not just controller? You should have an index() method in the pages controller which will get run when the controller is called with no extra segments.

Comment: That code is taken straight from http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html and the variable in page/view defaults to 'dashboard' if not given a value.

Comment: are you sure your server has mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: it appears as a "Loaded Module" in a call for `phpinfo();`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10749/discussion-between-rooneyl-and-phil-faceplant-young)

Comment: Just an idea but try changing ````$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';```` to ````$route['/(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';```` Note the /

Comment: We've worked out the routing is working (as the site will work with index.php in the url), it's just the redirect using mod_rewrite thats now the issue

Answer (score 4):

had your same problem just now , simply move .htaccess file to the root of your working directory
just take it out of application folder

Answer (score 2):

This is my htaccess file that I use for ALL projects:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Set the default file for indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # activate URL rewriting
    RewriteEngine on


    # do not rewrite links to the documentation, assets and public files
    RewriteCond $1 !^(images|assets|uploads|captcha)

    # do not rewrite for php files in the document root, robots.txt or the maintenance page
    RewriteCond $1 !^([^\..]+\.php|robots\.txt|maintenance\.html)

    # but rewrite everything else
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.

    ErrorDocument 404 index.php

</IfModule>
```

Then make sure in your config.php file:

```
  $config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: Thanks @Laurencei but we now know the server isn't allowing the redirect but I will use this when I sort that out! Thanks :)

Comment: where did you put that htaccess file anyway? @Laurence

Comment: @gumuruh - it goes into the base of your public www folder. Wherever your index.php file is.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I upgraded my PHP version on the server from 7.0 to 7.2.
However my CodeIgniter Routing stopped working after doing so. All requests were returning 300 error in browser console.

I resolved my issue by switching back to PHP 7.0.